# How do I HSTACK a variable number of columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I want to do some calculations on each of the columns of an array and afterwards I want to reassemble the columns into an array.

BYCOL doesn't work for this because it only allows returning a single value for each column and not a column vector.

I tried varies other approaches, like using HSTACK inside of REDUCE like in the following but none of those worked:

```
=LET(array,$A$6#,
REDUCE(CHOOSECOLS(array,1),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(array),2),LAMBDA(a,v,HSTACK(a,CHOOSECOLS(array,v)))))
```

EDIT: People asked for more clarity in the question and some sample data.

Given sample data like the following:
[image: Sample data]

and for example something like a CUMSUM (Cumulative SUM) function like the following:
[image: CUMSUM definition]

How could I produce the following output?

[image: Sample output]

Or alternatively, say I had a BOLLINGER function defined as:

```
=LAMBDA(arr,
    VSTACK(
        AVERAGE(arr)-STDEV.P(arr),
        AVERAGE(arr),
        AVERAGE(arr)+STDEV.P(arr)
    )
)
```

producing the following output:

[image: BOLLINGER output]

Comment: So what calculation do you want? Can you provide some sample (dummy) data using markdown table? Could you also share the expected result with that data?

Comment: I've added some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @Can.U made me realise the mistake in my original REDUCE formula which wasn't actually that far off. The following definition of APPLYCOL works for me now:
[image: APPLYCOL definition]

With APPLYCOL I can now simply apply CUMSUM to each column as follows:

[image: CUMSUM Solution]

or BOLLINGER:

[image: BOLLINGER Solution]

#### APPLYCOL definition

```
=LAMBDA(array, colfunc,
    REDUCE(
        colfunc(CHOOSECOLS(array,1)),
        SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(array) - 1,2),
        LAMBDA(accumulator,col,HSTACK(accumulator,colfunc(CHOOSECOLS(array, col))))
    )
)
```

Comment: A5   =MMULT(N(ROW(2:4)>COLUMN(A:C)),A1#)

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your intentions, I simply did two Reduce-based HSTACK column merge examples.

[image]
Example 1, the numeric column ^ its column value, and then merge the columns with HSTACK, for reference only

[image]
Example 2, modified as your original, choosecols(array,v) v will report an error if it is greater than columns(array), so it cannot return the result correctly.

```
=DROP(
      LET(array,A6#,
          REDUCE(CHOOSECOLS(array,1),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(array),2),
                 LAMBDA(a,v,HSTACK(a,IFERROR(10*CHOOSECOLS(array,v),"")))
                )
         ),,-1
     )
```

@snth
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your comment about the IFERROR showed me the error in my original ansatz which was due to a misunderstanding on my part of how SEQUENCE works (which is different to slices in say Python).

Answer (score 0):

`=LAMBDA(data,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(data),COLUMNS(data),LAMBDA(r,c,SUM(INDEX(TAKE(data,1),,c):INDEX(data,r,c)))))(A1:D3)`

So call the first part `CUMSUM` in the name manager: `=LAMBDA(data,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(data),COLUMNS(data),LAMBDA(r,c,SUM(INDEX(TAKE(data,1),,c):INDEX(data,r,c)))))`

Then use `=CUMSUM()` and use the range you need.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but my understanding of that is that it gives you a general CUMSUM. CUMSUM was only an example. I wanted a general APPLYCOL, which I think my solution provides.

Comment: With all due respect. This answered your example.

Comment: while I agree that it answered my example, it didn't answer my question. It's for this reason that I didn't initially include an example because I wasn't looking for a solution to a particular example but rather a general function that would work for any example.

Answer (score -1):

The best I have come up with so far is the following:

```
=LET(data,$F$20:$G$22,
APPLYBYCOL,LAMBDA(array,function,TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",FALSE,BYCOL(array,LAMBDA(col,SUBSTITUTE(ARRAYTOTEXT(function(col),0),", ",",")))),",",";"))),
APPLYBYCOL(data, LAMBDA(col, col)))
```

This seems rather unsatisfactory though as going via the text representation feels like a hack and this probably also isn't robust to data containing text with commas and semicolons.

Can anyone come up with something better?

Comment: *"Can anyone come up with something better?"*.... Could be interesting but you might want to provide more details first.